# Golang mysql client DB.Query method not reutning utf-8 encoded characters

Tags: mysql, go, utf-8

I have mysql table which has UTF-8 characters stored in some columns. The table was created with the DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

If I manually run the select statement I can see the UTF-8 characters but if I use the golang client and use the [DB.Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) method then I see that the characters are all garbled !

Also, the insert was done from the golang client as well. How come the insert was fine and the read is making it garbled ?
I couldn't see any parameters to set the character set while making the query. What am I missing ?

Comment: Client charset is a part of the connection procedure. Show how you're connecting to the databse.

Comment: There are about 5 different "garblings", which one did you get?  Possibly the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

So when the rows were inserted into the DB, the client charset was **latin1**. And the golang client by default was using utf8. Inserted all the rows again using utf8 and now the golang utf8 client seems to be reading the characters fine !

For others who come across similar problems:

The following command tells the current configuration

> mysql> status

The following command sets the client character set. Run it before insert statements.

> mysql> set names utf8

Comment: That's not the exactly correct way of doing it: there should be a connection option to specify a charset.